# Sign out a user using AuthenticationStateProvider and set User.Identity.IsAuthenticated to false using Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-server-side

I've inherited a website written in Blazor and .NET Core 3.1, and I need to provide a "Logout" button to the user. The website uses a custom implementation of [`AuthenticationStateProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.authorization.authenticationstateprovider?view=aspnetcore-3.1), with the following `GetAuthenticationStateAsync()` method:

```cs
public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
{
    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity();

    if (_currentUser != null)
    {
        identity = GenerateClaimsForCurrentUser();
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            var user = await sessionStorage.GetItemAsync<Credentials>("User");
            if (user != null && await IsAuthentic(user))
            {
                _currentUser = await UserInfo(user);
                identity = GenerateClaimsForCurrentUser();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
}
```

To verify the user is logged in, the code is:

```cs
AuthenticationState authState = await authenticationState.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
ClaimsPrincipal principal = authState.User;

if (principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    ...
}
```

The problem is in the `Logout()` method I've written, which is executed when the "Logout" link is clicked. I'm removing the "User" session from Blazor's session storage, but when `principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is called, it's still returning as `true`?

Does anyone know how I can set `IsAuthenticated` to `false` when logging out?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Steven. This is a really nice first post. It's clearly communicated, focused on one problem, includes the relevant code, and is tagged appropriately. I don't know the answer off the top of my head, but assume someone around here should be able to help out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In principle, your `GetAuthenticationStateAsync` method should be similar to this:

```
 public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var token = await GetTokenAsync();
        var identity = string.IsNullOrEmpty(token)
            ? new ClaimsIdentity()
            : new ClaimsIdentity(GenerateClaimsForCurrentUser(), "jwt");
        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
    }
```

Note: The `GetTokenAsync` method retrieves the JWT token from the local storage. If it's empty, you create a new `ClaimsIdentity` object with no claims. If it's not empty, you create a new `ClaimsIdentity` object that contains the claims you provide to it, and this object is passed to the `ClaimsPrincipal`’s constructor.

Comment: Thank you! I simplified the GetAuthenticationStateAsync() method to something very similar to your version and I now have logout functionality.

Comment: Hi, it would be good if you posted how your logout function removed the user and how you simplified the GetAuthenticationStatAsync so the whole solution is here.  I have the same issue but this post only provides a partial answer.